# How to change asynchronous process to run as a synchronous process

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have the following code

```
function runBat(){

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\runme.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);

        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }

    });

};

runBat();
```

If I'm correct the exec function is running asynchronously. How do I change this to run synchronously? I don't want to use any callbacks

Comment: You can't. Use promises to get rid of callbacks.

Comment: you have to use callbacks. Use 'async' module for synchronous processing.

Comment: @Abie *Use 'async' module for synchronous processing.* - No, once async function is introduced in the flow, nothing can make it synchronous processing.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr, what you pass in `Promise.then(callback)` is actually a callback

Comment: if you don't want to use callback, use a top-down lang like php

Comment: May I know how to use promises pr 'async' module in this scenario?

Comment: @TMA why do you need sync in first glance ? Why can't you tell your code to just wait until it gets the result (i.e use a callback)

Comment: @Kaiido I meant from code formatting point of view.

Comment: @dandavis- I only want to use Javascript, node.js

Comment: @Kaiido - This is only a segment of a program I have to wait till this bat file runs to run the next function, but it always got executed before this finishes. I tried callbacks, but didn't work. so that's wahy I thought of running this synchronously

Comment: From your code I can suspect that you are using node js exec function so if you wanna make it synchronous then use execSync function provided by node js. Here is the link : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function runBat(){

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var result = exec('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\runme.bat');
    console.log('result: ' + result);
};

runBat();
```